# React Component losing props after first render

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor

In this component I am using createContainer to get access to the collection and calling a session variable in order to query the collection with findOne.  When I first render the component, everything works fine and the collection is queried correctly.  However in the console.log methods.  I will have accurate information displayed on render, then immediately afterward the same variables will be undefined.

I added the setState as a way to try and save the state in the component, but the props are still dropping out (are almost immediately undefined after first render),  and I'm not sure why?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Email } from 'meteor/email';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

import {Tickets} from './tickets';

class ClaimButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      senderEmail: '',
      senderPhone: '',
      senderMessage: '',
      error: '',
      person: '',
      city: '',
      quantity: '',
      ticketNum: '',
      orderSum: ''
    }
    this.onClaimRequest = this.onClaimRequest.bind(this);
  }

  onClaimRequest(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {ticket} = this.props
    const claimTicketData = { person, city, quantity, ticketNum, orderSum };
    this.setState(claimTicketData);
    const {tikDta} = this.state;
    console.log(tikDta);
    let receiver = Meteor.settings.public.RECEIVER;
    Meteor.call('sendEmail',
      receiver,
      this.refs.senderEmail.value,
      'An event was claimed.',
      `Dear coordinator, A user claiming to be: ${tikDta.person} has initiated a claim in ${tikDta.city}, of ${tikDta.quantity}, at ${tikDta.ticketNum} ticket(s).  A total of ${tikDta.orderSum}.  During this version, please contact them directly to confirm their claim.
      Email: ${ this.refs.senderEmail.value}
      Phone:  ${this.refs.senderPhone.value}.
      Sender Message: ${ this.refs.senderMessage.value }
      Ticket Id Number: ${this.props.ticket._id}`
    );
}

  render() {
    console.log('claimButton', this.props.ticket);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="form-title">Claiming Ticket?</h1>
        <h2>Are you {this.props.ticket.person}?  Ready to claim {this.props.ticket.orderSum} in {this.props.ticket.city}? </h2>
        <h2>Quantity: {this.props.ticket.quantity}</h2>

        <form onSubmit={this.onClaimRequest}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="senderEmail">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" ref="senderEmail" className="form-control" id="senderEmail1" placeholder="Email" />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="SenderPhone">Contact telephone</label>
            <input type="tel" ref="senderPhone" className="form-control" id="SenderPhone1"/>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="SenderMessage">Messsage us</label>
            <textarea ref="senderMessage" className="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button className="btn btn-default" type="submit">Claim</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default createContainer(() => {
  const claimedTicket = Session.get('claimedTicket');
  Meteor.subscribe('tickets.claimed');
  const ticket = Tickets.findOne(claimedTicket);
  // console.log(ticket);
  return {ticket}
}, ClaimButton);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely an issue in the parent component. In React, whenever the parent's state is changed, all children will be re-rendered. The first time `ClaimButton`'s `render()` is called, it has the right props. However, something is going on in the parent class -- either the parent's state changed or some component farther up the ancestry chain had a state change -- which caused this component's props to change and trigger a re-render. I'd start your debugging efforts in the parent, since that's where the props are coming from.

Comment: As addition to that I would start debugging in `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` When nextProps is undefined, it is a high chance that the parent does change and now pass no props anymore. Also read:  https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops

Comment: I think this is on the right track...my session variable was being set by a button click event, so when the component changed, then re-rendered.  createContainer was having trouble accessing the session variable.   I also tried Tracker.autorun and had the same issue.  Because I did not need reactivity on this, I simply set state on first render and removed the createContainer from the component and everything is working fine.